# Xpage picture paste error

Tags: xpages

I am getting this error when pasting a picture in Xpage rich text editor and save the document; this mainly happens when picture size is big or resolution is good. Please let me know if there is any solution for the same?

```
Error while executing active content filter Exception in processing active content:
Exception in processing active content: 
Illegal state: 62 (>) Exception in processing active content: 
Illegal state: 62 (>)
```

Comment: Have you opened a PMR for this?

Comment: I do not have any PMR for this. I hope if you want you can easily reproduce it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the insert functionallity of CKEditor, the image is uploaded to the server first and then referenced in the CKEditor. But when pasting an image, it is encoded as a base64 string and added directly as a HTML image element:

```
<img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAADIAAAASXCAIAAACs2nJrAAAgAElEQVR4nOzdd3RVdb738fn7mZnnqjOOM6MztrFRLCjFQpFepRelKUhHWigJJQmBhE5IgCSk0EILNR1CEqpYriMlCc2uBPTe50raSSIK3uePvc+uv10UPBuP7"/>
```

As long as the image is small enough, the Active Content Filter (ACF) is able to parse the content of the CKEditor (HTML code), but as soon the pasted image is too large, the parser crashes.

Please try to disable the content filter by adding the *htmlFilter* properties set to *identify*:

```
<xp:inputRichText
    id="inputRichText1"
    value="#{document1.Body}"
    htmlFilterIn="identify"
    htmlFilter="identity">
</xp:inputRichText>
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

This would allow users to embed "malicious" HTML code.

Comment: Thanks ; this helps to eliminate the error. But does it have any other impact? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If it's caused by the file size, this may be getting restricted by the "Maximum size of request content" in the HTTP Protocol Limits section on the Internet Protocols > HTTP tab of the server document. You may also need to change the "Maximum POST data (in
kilobytes):" setting in the POST Data section of the Internet Protocols > Domino Web Engine tab.

Comment: But if I convert it to png file and use image insert option to add it to CKEditor with out any issue; even it works fine like this for larger pictures also; but issue mainly happens for direct copy & paste which is my need.

Comment: Also in domino log the below message is displayed... 12/04/2014 02:37:03 PM  HTTP JVM: SEVERE: Error while executing active content filter
12/04/2014 02:37:03 PM  HTTP JVM: com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet$ExtendedServletException: javax.faces.FacesException: Error while executing active content filter
12/04/2014 02:37:03 PM  HTTP JVM: SEVERE: CLFAD0134E: Exception processing XPage request